# Управление компьютером через командную строку C#

Tags: android, c#, cmd

Возникла идея сделать управление компьютером через телефон. Управлять планирую с помощью командной строки, то есть на телефоне сделать импровизированый терминал который отправляет мои команды, компьютер принимает их , и отправляет ответ.Поэтому возник вопрос: как в c# можно обращаться к командной строке? Какие темы стоит освоить для такого?

Comment: Да какие угодно. Такое можно сделать почти всем, что передает на сервер данные (REST API, JSON/XML-RPC, Обычный TCP сервер, WCF и др.). Ведь вам достаточно взять текстовую команду, отправить на сервер, обработать ее и вернуть результат, а это делают все серверные реализации...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ то что сервак надо делать это понятно. А как потом прикрутить cmd? Может библиотека какая нужна или они уже встроены

Comment: Если нужна вся консоль (что я не советую делать), то можно просто запустить через Process.Start команду. Если не весь набор, то делаете свои отдельные методы, каждый будет отвечать за что то свое (пинг к примеру).

Comment: А не проще поднять на компьютере какой-нибудь SSH-сервер? А то и вовсе telnet.

Comment: @Yaant легких путей не ищем)

Comment: В Гугле плей страниц 10 варезов на эту тему, рекомендую скачать что то готовое, перед тем как изобретать велосипед :) за одно увидите как там все организовано, если останется желание ваять свое.

Comment: @NewView я хочу попрактиковаться во всем. Сейчас набросал примерный список программ, которые в дальнейшем создать хочу. Да и для портфолио это хорошо. Я то понимаю что уже давным давно все придумано, но хотя бы иметь опыт написания таких программ надо)

Comment: Вы пропустили самую главную часть любого сетевого обмена данными - это безопасность, шифрование, авторизация, фильтрация по источнику (ip,network,asn) и тд. Так что рекомендую начать с фильтрации по IP, создать ACL списки например :) потом будет яснее куда двигаться.

Comment: @NewView спасибо за совет)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для доступа к Вводу/Выводу cmd.exe вы должны запустить процесс:

```
var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",  
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
var readStream = proc.StandardOutput;
var writeSteram = proc.StandardInput;
```

И дальше работаете со Stream-ами.

Теперь Вам необходимо передавать команды с телефона.
Это может быть или Socket или Http протокол. Как Вам угодно.